# CSS Only applies on old local IP (xampp)

Tags: css, wordpress, xampp

I have a wordpress installation on a local machine. I have it configured to point to 192.168.76.61 so that I can access it on my phone to test the mobile theme I'm working on. This was working fine last week and I have been off so haven't bothered checking. Coming back in to work today the IP address changed to 192.168.76.71 which locked me out of the WP admin and from accessing the site. I changed the references my local database to reflect the change and I can now log in to the admin. It also loaded the CSS and everything properly on phone and host machine. On inspection of the settings I noticed that the WP address URL was what I changed it to, but the site address URL was the old one (76.61 instead of 76.71). So I changed this to .71 but it now does not load any stylesheets but it has the correct links etc. Changing it back to .61 loads the CSS correctly but only allows me to access the front page. Any ideas?

Comment: Maybe something related to cache plugins? If you have some, you should deactivate them while working offline.

Comment: I have no cache plugins activated although they are in the plugins folder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you should try a search and replace script like this one:

https://interconnectit.com/products/search-and-replace-for-wordpress-databases/

With it's help you can change all old IPs to the new one. Because there might be some other relations in your database that you won't find with an standard search and replace.

You just have to put the script in your root, open it in your browser and fill out the form. The database info is filled in automatically. If you press "live run" it will replace everything that matches.

Hope it helps!

Comment: Thanks. I have seen this script before, but I managed to fix it by rechoosing my homepage again. Weird. Marking this as accepted answer as this would solve the problem.